# Chrome hides HTML5 video when switching tab

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, video

I'm experincing this error on my homepage, when switching tabs in Chrome:

[image]

The error does not seem to happen in either Safari og Firefox. Tried on Chrome, Safari and Firefox on MacOS and Firefox and Chrome on Ubuntu. Chrome is the only browser having trouble with this.

Specifically it sets the CSS display attribute to `display: none;` which I can't wrap my head around.

Try it for yourself: https://supervisual.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about chrome, it's something on that website code or something that makes that, try right click on the video and open in new tab, that issue doesn't happen when switching tabs then.

Comment: There was indeed a script pausing the video. Website was built on pre-existing code from Designmodo's Startup Framework, so should've checked better. Thanks for solving this!